# problems using a brightcove player in AS3 project (Security sandbox violation)

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain

I hope someone can help with this as I can't find an answer anywhere.

I've created an AS3 based UI slider that displays images and videos. The videos are added using a brightcove player. This is all working ok except when I click play on the video I get the following error.

SecurityError: Error #2123: Security sandbox violation: BitmapData.draw: file:///D|/development/videoplayer/VideoBanner.swf cannot access rtmp://brightcove-76.fcod.llnwd.net:1935/a500/d12?videoId=696716426001&lineUpId=696887476001&pubId=1520968877&playerId=695954425001&affiliateId=. No policy files granted access.

I'm using a custom play/pause button, and this seems to work (ie, it plays the video) but then I see this error pop up, and my info panels stop working (these are just panels with titles and info copy on them. Animated in using TweenMax).

I gather from some searches that this might be a cross domain problem. I've tried to set up the brightcove player to accept the URL I'm testing it on but I still get the error. Looking at the support site for brightcove I can find nothing about a cross domain policy.
I realise that the error above is running locally but the same thing is happening on my test page.

Has anyone come across this problem before using brightcove and AS3? Let me know if you need any extra info.

Cheers

Barry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a crossdomain.xml file like below on your web root?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did try that yes. In the end it turned out to be an issue I was having with the brightCove API. Sorry I should have updated.